# If there's going to be a json(b) column regardless, what data should still have its own column?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I welcome for generic answers, but I'll also provide a slightly abstracted version of my specific situation

I have a Page model that uses the Ancestry gem to organize itself into a tree for sitemap and nav purposes

Each page is going to have a jsonb column for miscellaneous options, but there's a couple values where I'm not sure if they should be in the jsonb column or a separate one of their datatype.

- hidden : Boolean
  If true, a page will not be included in the nav menu.
  It will mostly be accessed in whole-tree operations along with other data
  I'm thinking this should be a column to allow for easily culling hidden pages from queries.
- redirect : String
  If any value but nil, will redirect to that value instead of rendering that page's content.
  I don't expect this to be utilized often, but the fact that its value will be read every time a page is loaded could justify a column.

I'm also open to explanations on why going for jsonb here is a bad idea, but from a "what if" standpoint I'd still like an answer where a jsonb column must exist.

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

Use individual columns if:

- They are meaningful as a unique key;
- They are foreign keys;
- They're likely to be updated a lot in changes that don't change the rest of the data
- They benefit from richer data types and semantics
- They're DB structure not part of the payload data
- They're likely to be useful for index predicates

Sometimes it's also worth splitting them out for indexing, but expression indexes, GIN and GiST, etc make that less important.

Sometimes it's worth duplicating data within the json payload as a separate column and maintaining that duplication with a trigger. That way you get to keep it in the payload, while keeping a copy as a separate column for use as an index predicate or whatever.